# Merging multiple text files column wise in python

Tags: python, error-handling, merge, array-merge

I have 51 .dat files of my target star in 51 different orbits with coordinates (x,y) specified between a min. and a max. which I want to extract out of multiple .dat files for different orbits. I extracted the required files by specifying the min. max. for my target star. The .dat files are in the form [mjd, cts, cts_error], but the .dat files having only 1 row of values are look very different even though I've added the delimiter as '/t'. It is shown here.

only 1 row .dat file

[image]

```
import glob
import re
for i in range(51):
    os.chdir(r'C:/Users/Abhinna Sundar/Desktop/MS Thesis/AR UMa/L2 data/archive/20160522_G05_045T01_9000000468_level2/uvit/RAS_VIS/uvt_'+f'{i+1:02}'+'/N_'+f'{i+1:02}'+'/')
    myFiles = glob.glob('*.dat')
    for f in myFiles:
        regex = re.compile(r'\d+')
        nums=[int(x) for x in regex.findall(f)] ### getting integer values from the filename
        x_c=nums[0]
        y_c=nums[1]
        if (2400<x_c and x_c<2700):
            if (2300<y_c and y_c<2700):
                new=np.loadtxt(f, delimiter='\t')
                np.savetxt('C:/Users/Abhinna Sundar/Desktop/MS Thesis/AR UMa/L2 data/Orbit_Data/Source/bin_60s/NUV/S_nuv_O'+f'{i+1:02}'+'_lc.dat',new, delimiter='\t')
```

Now, even though I've manually changed it so that is is of the form [mjd, cts, cts_error], the next problem is that I want to merge all 51 .dat files of my target column wise.
Below is my python code for merging them column wise.

```
nuv_files=glob(r'C:/Users/Abhinna Sundar/Desktop/MS Thesis/AR UMa/L2 data/Orbit_Data/Source/bin_60s/NUV/*.dat')
S_nuv_MJD=[]
S_nuv_cts=[]
S_nuv_cts_err=[]
for i in range(5):
    sample= np.loadtxt(nuv_files[i], delimiter='\t')
    mjd=sample[0]
    cts=sample[1]   
    cts_err=sample[2]
    S_nuv_MJD.extend(mjd)
    S_nuv_cts.extend(cts)
    S_nuv_cts_err.extend(cts_err)
    S_nuv_final_rand=np.c_[S_nuv_MJD, S_nuv_cts, S_nuv_cts_err]
    mjd_values=S_nuv_final_rand[:,0]
    cts_values=S_nuv_final_rand[:,1]
    cts_err_values=S_nuv_final_rand[:,2]
    M, C, E=zip(*sorted(zip(mjd_values,cts_values,cts_err_values)))
    S_nuv_final=np.c_[M,C,E]

np.savetxt('C:/Users/Abhinna Sundar/Desktop/MS Thesis/AR UMa/L2 data/Orbit_Data/Source/bin_60s/S_nuv_60s_final.txt',S_nuv_final, delimiter='\t')
```

Python is showing this error for the ones having only 1 column.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-331-54536de9c3cb> in <module>
      9     cts=sample[1]
     10     cts_err=sample[2]
---> 11     S_nuv_MJD.extend(mjd)
     12     S_nuv_cts.extend(cts)
     13     S_nuv_cts_err.extend(cts_err)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

When I'm trying to display my arrays, it shows this for the first file (haing only 1 row, and similarly for other .dat files having only 1 row).

Display of 1st row of each .dat file

[image]

How to merge all the text files here in this case, and resolve my error?

Comment: This is very confusing. Are you saying that all of your source data files have the 3 values split over 3 lines and you want to correct them so that there's only one line with 3 delimited values?

Comment: The files having only 1 row looks like [.....] and files having more than 1 row looks like [[...]]. How do I correct for [..] this thing?

Comment: Please show examples of the various different formats of input files